# How to make entire text of a long label visible?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

We have a long text that needs to be wrapped and when tried in D3.js, the entire text isn't visible. I tried multiple options to wrap but actually unable to get the code fit.

I see that `tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight * dy + "em").text(word);` line calculates the length but i am unable to understand how to dynamically fit the text / make long text visible.

My TSV:

```
name    value
Committed 671 birthdays to it if there is a relevant source of information , it would be better to understand it and kids can be assigned relevant groups to particiate     .19
it should end up like this in the $_POST[] array (PHP format for easy   .19
just leave it there    .19
Ex is doing too well    .10
High school friends all dead now    .15
Discovered how to “like” things mentally    .27
```

My code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.7/d3.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.title {
  font: bold 14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 80, right: 180, bottom: 80, left: 180},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, .3);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(8, "%");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.name; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .attr("x", x(data[0].name))
      .attr("y", -26)
      .text("Why Are We Leaving Facebook?");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
      .call(wrap, x.rangeBand());

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.name); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
});

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),



        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight * dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's do the proper attribution: that function called `wrap` was created by Mike Bostock, as you can see here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321. You probably copied it from there or from the countless copies that we can find on the internet.

That being said, this answer will propose a solution using that function as it is. Of course better and more performant solutions exist.

Let's suppose you have a long label, like this:

```
"What would you think if I sang out of tune? 
Would you stand up and walk out on me?
Lend me your ears and I'll sing you a song 
And I'll try not to sing out of key"
```

In this proposed solution, we set a counter...

```
var counter = 0;
```

... and, inside the `wrap` function, we get the maximum number of lines:

```
counter = lineNumber > counter ? lineNumber : counter;
```

With that information, we can use a magic number (for instance, `20`) to multiply for the maximum number of lines and push the axis upwards:

```
margin.bottom = 20 * counter;
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
y.range([height, 0]);
```

Here is Bostock's code with that modification: https://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/91f656cf425cb630a4e5adf98d207f35/bcda7bdb86ffffdd84000a075811ea17d4f4218a

There are duplications and unnecessary steps here, which you can improve: this answer is just a rough demo to show you a way to calculate the necessary space needed for the labels.